# Should we split the waves tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed that we currently tag questions about waves at the ocean surface and seismic waves with the same [waves](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/waves) tag. There are other topics about waves, which could come up here. Should we split the tag? If so, what tag names should we use?

Comment: As long as those questions have *multiple* tags, the remaining tags should reasonably disambiguate the matter.

Comment: Some options are "surface gravity waves", "ocean waves",  "planetary waves", "atmospheric waves" and "seismic waves". Any of them could be appropriate. My preference is to leave it at "seismic waves" and "ocean" and "atmospheric waves". The fact is that if people start being more specific about their tags (e.g., "Kelvin waves") then those will get added as well.